# textbox in line better solution

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Today i just (coded in asp.net C#) , i have two cases below , just want to grab your attention that which is better way of doing from the below case.

CASE 1:

```
textbox1.Text=textbox2.Text=textbox3.Text=textbox4.Text="";
```

to emplty textboex in asp.net.Previously i was using

CASE 2:

```
textbox1.Text="";
textbox2.Text="";
textbox3.Text="";
textbox4.Text="";
```

I can also navigate all control type of textbox and than empty it.( but please don't think about it.)

My concern here is which is the better way according to performance CASE 1 or CASE 2.

Comment: This is premature optimization. Care about readability and maintainability, not about 0.00000000000000000001% more or less cpu cycles. Nobody will ever notice it. But apart from that, if you ever ask yourself whether approach 1 is faster or approach 2, check it out yourself. Or with the [words of Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/): _"If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses."_

Comment: what if i still want to know :-) , Do you know which is better, I will be thankful to you. I am curious ;-)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: @techsolver: i have edited my first comment. Check it out yourself. Learn how to use the `Stopwatch`. You will notice that there is no noticeable difference.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  , good explanation , but it's a diplomatic one :-) . Thanks anyways .

Comment: @Paul -- you could edit question and remove wrong tag :)

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but the poster is likely to make the same mistake again.